# How to remove Kylin GUI completely and install Kubuntu GUI?

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, gui, desktop-environments

After installing a theme from the internet to my Kubuntu 16.04, I am having issues with the system (GUI completely gone, only black screen).

I followed instructions available across various forum. Like: reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` but it should be `ubuntukylin-desktop` ([Ubuntu Kylin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Kylin) is the official Chinese version), but then I found... remove some packages likewise. Finally I got the splash-screen but am still not able to use the system... <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> terminal is working perfectly.

What could I do now to resolve this? Is it possible to completely remove the GUI (including all settings) and reinstall Kubuntu GUI?

Comment: What GUI are you trying to remove?

Comment: As I mentioned I want to remove Ubuntu kylin GUI and reinstall it including unity

Comment: That's confusing because your question says you want to reinstall Kubuntu, not kylin.

Comment: Someone had edited the question ... I want to completely remove and reinstall the gui

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sudo apt-get remove 'ubuntukylin*'` to remove kylin desktop and all dependencies.

I suggest you to reset all the keyboard shortcuts too. For me some shortcuts was disabled, e.g: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to minimize all the windows.

If you just use `apt-get remove ubuntukylin-desktop` it will not remove all the data.

For file manager ukuy removal:

```
sudo apt-get remove 'peony*'
```

More ukuy data:

```
sudo apt-get remove 'ukuy*'
```